# grep output different on two servers

Tags: grep

I am trying to create a script, and one part requires showing lines with numeric values.

My basic syntax is:

```
echo $i | grep [0-9]
```

For example, I set `i=12345`, it should output `12345`.

But on one server, it doesn't output anything (exactly the same commands).

I do not know how to Google this issue, I have tried "grep output different on other server", to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

When using a regexp, either use `egrep` or `grep -e` to make sure the pattern is not treated as a plain string.

Comment: Did you use quotes as Noir Levy suggested? There might be a file called "5" in that directory or something.

Comment: I used " " and it worked. One last question, should I use "-e" everytime I use brackets on grep?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a shell issue? some shells interpert [] differently
try

```
echo "1234" | grep "[0-9]"
```

(with quotes)

also try

```
grep --version
```

to see if there is a different grep version